# Read a file line by line using Lambda / S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I want to read a file line by line located on S3. I tried the following code which I found searching online, but the Lambda function is exiting without invoking any of the readline callbacks. What am I doing wrong?

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new aws.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });
const readline = require('readline');

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    const key = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    const params = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: key,
    };

    const s3ReadStream = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();

    const rl = readline.createInterface({
      input: s3ReadStream,
      terminal: false
    });

    rl.on('line', (line) => {
      console.log(`Line from file: ${line}`);
    });
    rl.on('error', () => {
        console.log('error');
    });
    rl.on('close', function () {
        console.log('closed');
        context.succeed();
    });
    console.log('done');
};
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've found the problem. It's being awhile that I haven't coded on Lambda and I thought it would only exit when context was called. I'm now waiting for the promise to be resolved (or rejected which I'll implement later).

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new aws.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });
const readline = require('readline');

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    const key = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    const params = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: key,
    };
    const s3ReadStream = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();

    const rl = readline.createInterface({
      input: s3ReadStream,
      terminal: false
    });

    let myReadPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        rl.on('line', (line) => {
          console.log(`Line from file: ${line}`);
        });
        rl.on('error', () => {
            console.log('error');
        });
        rl.on('close', function () {
            console.log('closed');
            resolve();
        });
    });

    try { await myReadPromise; }
    catch(err) {
        console.log('an error has occurred');
    }

    console.log('done reading!');
};
```

Comment: Jesus man.... you saved my life... I spent 8 hrs trying to figure out why it didn't work. It was your exact solution....

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution! I had the same issue but couldn't get it to run. My code works great on my local machine, but times out on lambda. I tried running your code and also timed out. It seems the 'line' callback is never being called. Are there any additional steps you took to make this work?

Comment: @davidrac have you increased the lambda function timeout?

Comment: Should probably call `reject()` in the on error handler.

Answer (score 0):

`getObject` doesn't just return the object that was stored S3. It return a JSON object whose `Body` field holds the blob of the object stored to S3. See also in the `Response` part of the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property).

Comment: Thanks. I was based myself on this code:

https://gist.github.com/maxrabin/e3e51abc365cd3f54d78

Do you know of how I can accomplish what I want?

Comment: @Raisen Interesting. If the code you linked to ever worked, then my answer is probably wrong. What does sticks out is the fact that you're using a mix of `async` and `context.succeed` (legacy style Lambda programming). Why not stick to either the code as it appears in the link, or rewrite it using promises exclusively?

Comment: I've figured out the problem. You were right, promises helped to resolve this. Thanks for your help!